# connecting raspberry pi 4 to external screen or control without changing any settings (broken touchscreen)

Tags: hdmi, touchscreen, screen, output

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 connected to the original touchscreen. A few days ago, the display stopped working. The system controlled by the pi seems to still be working, so the fault seems to lie in the screen or the signal transduction between Pi and screen.

Does anyone know of a way to change the visual output without the ability to adjust any settings?

I've already tried using an ethernet crossover cable to connect the Pi to a laptop, and connecting it to a computer screen via HDMI cable and adapter, both without success. Since the Pi is attached to the device it's controlling, the ribbon cable for the touchscreen can't be easily removed. This means that the screen is apparently still registered as connected, so it won't switch to HDMI output without changes to the config file.
An ethernet connection seems to always require an ssh to be set up from the Raspberry.

My last idea is to try adjusting the config settings blind, which I'm hesitant to do. Is there another obvious solution I'm missing?

Comment: a serial terminal at a serial port may work

Comment: What OS? Why don't you just enable ssh or just take the SD Card to another computer?